# How to include format in url that is generated from Django Rest Framework's HyperlinkedModelSerializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to have the url field that is generated by `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` to include the query parameters of the current request. That way when I'm browsing via the browsable api the links will go to their respect browsable api pages.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Ideally I'd like a way to easily add this to all of my serializers (perhaps overriding `HyperlinkedRelatedField`?).

So far all I have is...:

```
the_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_the_url(self, object):
    print self.context['request'].GET.get('format')
```

that gets me the `format` but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: When you click on a hyperlinked model relation from your browsable api, doesn't it open that related model in the browsable api again? (it's possible that I misunderstood the reason for the question)

Comment: No it doesn't, presumably because my first renderer is TemplateHTMLRenderer, not BrowsableAPIRenderer. To view anything in the browsable api the query parameter format=api has to be present, but in the urls generated it's not there.

Comment: makes sense. did you try opening the endpoint with the .api suffix? according to the docs these should be preserved. can't check this now but I'm curious and will try that tomorrow.

Comment: The .api suffix is the issue - the urls generated don't also have the .api suffix so when you click on them they go to the html version.

Comment: I see. wondering if this might be a bug, since [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield) explicitly state "If using format suffixes, hyperlinked fields will use the same format suffix for the target unless overridden by using the format argument.".

Comment: It does work with the suffix after all.  It just wasn't working with the suffix for that particular model because I had overridden the retrieve method in a manner it didn't like.  Thank you!